# Very slow loading, htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I got a big problem, gallery  in my website load very slow 
http://mayshastudio.com/gallery/wiola-i-robert/ or http://mayshastudio.com/gallery/kasia-i-maciek/
i add to my htaccess that code:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size 128M
php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
php_value memory_limit 1G
php_value max_execution_time 259200
php_value max_input_time 259200
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
```

and it didn't help, what can i do? Any ideas?

Comment: Was your site fast before you added this to your .htaccess?

Comment: The load time of your site has little to do with `.htaccess` and everything to do with making 256 load requests and download 7Mb+ of images before you display anything. There is significant optimisation you can do on the site content to improve matters. Look at PageSeed and fix what it tells you to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what @Fouad Fodail has said;

> You are loading a lot of images at once. 208 images with total weight of 8188K. that's too much. try to load only thumbnails or load them gradually using ajax.

You can look at the browser development panel - in Google Chrome, press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `I`, and navigate to the network panel, where you can see the requests being made. Hopefully when you've got a 'visual' representation of that, you can start optimizing your site.

- Cache images
- Load images via AJAX requests
- Optimize the images - save in JPEG, rather PNG

In conclusion, to make your site faster; ***optimize everything*** - it's vague, I know, and time consuming, but it'll be worth it for the end user experience whilst browsing.

*A screengrab of the network panel*

[See Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLvhK.png)

Furthermore, read this [article](http://moz.com/blog/15-tips-to-speed-up-your-website)

*Basic summary;*

- Leverage browser caching
- Enable Keep-Alive
- Enable gzip compression
- Make landing page redirects cacheable
- Use a CDN
- Content elements
- Minimize redirects
- Remove query strings from static resources
- Specify a character set
- Minify your codes
- Avoid bad requests
- Serve resources from a consistent URL
- Reduce DNS lookups
- Optimize images
- Put CSS at the top and JS at the bottom

Some won't be that relevant to your situation, but they're worth noting.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading a lot of images at once. 208 images with total weight of 8188K. that's too much. try to load only thumbnails or load them gradually using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

[**Start here**](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http://mayshastudio.com/gallery/wiola-i-robert/&tab=desktop) the link goes to Google Page Speed. It will identify exactly why your site is not loading quickly.

Then download **[this plugin](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=http://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/&ei=vHuIUqLJGsvqkQeKwYCICw&usg=AFQjCNFfdRNBQ2EdtbLgwetrBFuOm0Mw9g&sig2=jmjzDEgJ_UvCDcXgXzNpDw)** W3 Total Cache. There is a learning curve associated but its a comprehensive solution and important if you want visitors to stay on your page. Be careful with the minify setting until you get a handle on things. When JS gets minified like this it can have some strange effects.

In my opinion, a lot of the pictures that you have are sort of the same thing(same place and same time). Show more variety in the top few rows and remove some of the pictures from the bottom.... It's just too many pictures to load for a home page. I think people understand if they have to wait for a gallery to load but on a homepage you only have a few seconds before you lose a visitors attention.